# Magura mt5- non stop micro bubbles coming out while bleeding

Tags: brakes, magura

I have a problem bleeding my Magura MT5 brakes.

I used two 50-ml syringes and the EZ MTB bleed kit. I pushed fluid from the syringe attached to the caliper to the top (at the lever) and back again.

I repeated the process over 10 times, aligning the lever at multiple angles until no more air came out while pushing the fluid. Then I pulled the brake lever until it touched handlebar.

Then I pushed the fluid and saw more bubbles come out. The problem is that after pulling the lever, the bubbles never stop coming out, even after repeating the process.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have a block between the two brake pads when you pulled the lever?

Comment: Yes i had it installed the whole time.

Comment: Last time this happened to me, the syringe fitting O-ring seal was leaking.

Comment: Maybe this can help?  It seems a similar situation: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/76789/atomized-bubbles-while-following-park-process-to-bleed-magura-mt5?rq=1

Comment: Im gonna change the o ring thanks. What do yall think about using only one syringe at the lever? I think its called vacuum bleeding?

Comment: From how you write the order you're doing this in, it makes it sound like when you pull the lever, the lever syringe is empty or nearly empty. Are you? Don't do that.

Comment: @Amarider look up gravity bleed on YouTube,  you might get better results with a top to bottom fill.

Comment: The syringe wasn't empty. I just did the vacum bleed, no More air comes out, but when i press the lever there is still a bunch of micro bubbles showing up. Maybe I just shouldn't press the lever all the way to the handlebars, or at all. Link to the metod i used https://youtu.be/Bl8PChRadX0